# Pandas: Key error in merge after creating index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have large data frame to merge into make sure the the merge take place in multiprocessing manner I decided to use indexes. But after creating indexes I get key error.

For example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'], 'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3']})
(Pdb) df1
    A   B
0  A0  B0
1  A1  B1
2  A2  B2
3  A3  B3
```

But second DataFrame:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'], 'C': ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4']})
(Pdb) df2
    A   C
0  A0  C1
1  A1  C2
2  A2  C3
3  A3  C4
```

Now I set indexes for both the data frames where column `A` is the index.

```
df1.set_index('A', inplace=True)
df2.set_index('A', inplace=True)

(Pdb) df1
     B
A     
A0  B0
A1  B1
A2  B2
A3  B3

(Pdb) df2
     C
A     
A0  C1
A1  C2
A2  C3
A3  C4
```

Now when I do the merge:

```
(Pdb) result = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='A')
*** KeyError: 'A'
```

But if I do this without creating index merge take place without a key error.

```
(Pdb) df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'], 'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3']})
(Pdb) df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'], 'C': ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4']})
(Pdb) result = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='A')
(Pdb) result
    A   B   C
0  A0  B0  C1
1  A1  B1  C2
2  A2  B2  C3
3  A3  B3  C4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you merge **on the index**, you should both:

- not specify the key in `merge`
- use the `left_index = True`, `right_index = True` arguments to `merge`

otherwise, you have to explicitely tell what your key is using `key =`

Comment: I want to speed up the merge thats why I wanted to create the index. But I tried left_index=True still getting the key error.

Comment: if both your keys are indeces, you should use both `left_index` AND `right_index`

Comment: `(Pdb) result2 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='A', left_index=True, right_index=True)
*** KeyError: 'A'` looks like still same error

Comment: buddy drop that key ! :) `pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)`

Answer (score 0):

When you specify `on=A` you're telling Pandas that you want to use the column A to do the merge. When you make A the index, it's no longer a column in the frame.
You can either merge, and then make A the index, or make A the index and then specify `left_index=True` and `right_index=True`.